# no extensions showing with ./mage list-installed

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a whole list of extension .xml files in var/package, all readable by web user but when I do ./mage list-installed nothing shows at all so I can't manage any of them. Can anyone suggest what I can do.
Running CE 1.8.1.
Thanks.

UPDATE:
found that downloader/cache.cfg looks corrupt. Can't read it via ssh at any rate.

Can I recreate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i remember it was like that:

```
./mage clear-cache
./mage sync
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it and then run `mage mage-setup`, it will recreate it